# Усовершенствование скрипта для защиты от xss and sql inject

Tags: защита, php

```
class jms_security
{
    function security($str)
    {
        $fail = 0;       
        @stripos($str, "'") !== false ? $fail = 1 : @stripos($str, '"') !== false ? $fail = 1 : @stripos($str, '%3E') !== false ? $fail = 1 : @stripos($str, '%3C') !== false ? $fail = 1 : "";
        return $fail;
    }

    function clear()
    {
        global $post_text,$get_text,$cook_text,$num_post,$num_get,$num_cook;
        unset($post_text,$get_text,$cook_text,$num_post,$num_get,$num_cook);
    }
}

$post_text = "";
$get_text  = "";
$cook_text = "";

foreach($_POST as $i => $value){$post_text.=stripslashes($_POST[$i])." ";}
foreach($_GET as $i => $value){$get_text.=stripslashes($_GET[$i])." ";}
foreach($_COOKIE as $i => $value){$cook_text.=stripslashes($_COOKIE[$i])." ";}

$security = new jms_security;
$num_post = $security->security($post_text);
$num_get  = $security->security($get_text);
$num_cook = $security->security($cook_text);
$result   = ($num_post+$num_get+$num_cook);
$security->clear();

if ($result != 0) die('Hacking attempt!');
```

Что можно усовершенствовать или переделать?

Comment: Зачем класс? Да и вообще с точки зрения ООП это плохой код.

Comment: Да класс, ну, что поделаешь. )) Для чего я обратился к вам? Помочь улучшить творение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы просто не использовать htmlspecialchars?

Comment: Так этот класс вставляется в начале файла главного... А данный класс предотвращает проникновение хакеров на сайт хД.

Comment: $HTTP_POST_VARS ты всё ещё на php 3 ?

Comment: Все спасибо поменял на $_POST